# Fetch function in React Native not working when sending SMS

Tags: node.js, react-native, twilio, fetch

Fetch function works in postman, but not in react-native, while trying to send an SMS with twilio API

I am trying to make an app that sends an sms when a button is pressed. In my onPress, i use this function.

```
SendMessage = () => {
  try {
    fetch("https://api.twilio.com/2010-04-01/Accounts/[AccountSID]/Messages.json", {
      body: "To=[toPhoneNumber]&From=[fromPhoneNumber]&Body=[message]=",
      headers: {
        Authorization: "Basic [Auth]",
        "Cache-Control": "no-cache",
        "Content-Type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"
      },
      method: "POST"
    })
  }
  catch (err) {
    console.log("Error fetching data-----------", err);
  }
}
```

When i press the button nothing happens. please bear over with me because i am new to react native.

Comment: I think you should send stringified object  in body key.

Comment: did you change the code to out it here or you are just using this code in your app? some params are missing here or hardcoded which may be the reason. it would help alot if you could `log` and share the response or any execption occuring

Comment: I have changed the code to be able to out it here. In my own code i have the correct AccountSID and so on. I will try to share response soon.